# Plotting the sum of multiple plot lines

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have plotted multiple lines using data from arrays. The thing is that i want to plot a new line that shows the sum of all these lines. Keep in mind that the x values from each set are different. 
Let me give an example of what i am trying to do. Let's say i have 2 sets of (x,y) data like this:

```
 x1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
 y1=np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
 x2=np.array([3,4,5,6,7])
 y2=np.array([2,4,6,8,10])
```

Then, i use np.interp

```
 xvals1=np.linspace(1,5,1000)
 yinterp1 = np.interp(xvals1, x1, y1)
 plt.plot(xvals1, yinterp1)
 xvals2=np.linspace(3,7,1000)
 yinterp2 = np.interp(xvals2, x2, y2)
 plt.plot(xvals2, yinterp2)
```

Ok, so now, i want an extra line that shows the sum of these 2 lines. But if i do the following, it gives me a line(green colour) that is definitely wrong:

```
xvals=np.linspace(1,7,1000)
plt.plot(xvals,yinterp1+yinterp2)
```

[image: image of the plot is here]

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: What is wrong? The `y` data has no way to know which `x` makes sense. You are plotting a `x, y` set with the same amount of points for both so it raises no error. The only data that is valid is `yinterp1[1 <= xvals1 & xvals1 <= 5]` and `yinterp2[3 <= xvals2 & xvals2 <= 7]`.

Comment: When you do `y1+ y2`, the result is `[y1[0]+y2[0], y1[1]+y2[1], ...]`. In your specific case, the indexes correspond to different values so you're effectively doing `[y1[x=1]+y2[x=3], ..., y1[x=5]+y2[x=7]]` which has no physical meaning.

Comment: yes, i get what you're saying. All i said is what i tried to do because i didn't have any other idea, i know it is wrong and that's why i posted this question, to find the right way to do it

Comment: Oh no problem then, it is just a matter of masking the data! Please see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `y1+ y2`, the result is `[y1[0]+y2[0], y1[1]+y2[1], ...]`. In your specific case, the indexes correspond to different values so you're effectively doing `[y1[x=1]+y2[x=3], ..., y1[x=5]+y2[x=7]]` which has no physical meaning.

We need to **mask** the values so that they make sense and the `y` are "aligned" for an addition. By aligned, I mean that the same index corresponds to the same `x`.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y1 = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
x2 = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
y2 = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

xvals1 = np.linspace(1, 5, 1000)
yinterp1 = np.interp(xvals1, x1, y1)
plt.plot(xvals1, yinterp1)

xvals2 = np.linspace(3, 7, 1000)
yinterp2 = np.interp(xvals2, x2, y2)
plt.plot(xvals2, yinterp2)

xvals = np.linspace(1, 7, 1000)
x1_and_x2_intersection_mask = (np.logical_and(3 <= xvals, xvals <= 5))
xinter = xvals[x1_and_x2_intersection_mask]
yi1 = yinterp1[x1_and_x2_intersection_mask]
yi2 = yinterp2[x1_and_x2_intersection_mask]
plt.plot(xinter, yi1+yi2)
```

Now regarding your comment, remove the last line of the above code and add this:

```
def mask_between_a_b(array, a, b):
    """I make functions when I have to use something more than once."""
    return np.logical_and(a <= array, array <= b)

# Create the masked data for the two regions where blue and orange don't share an x.
x1_mask = mask_between_a_b(x1, 1, 3)
x2_mask = mask_between_a_b(x2, 5, 7)

x1m = x1[x1_mask]
y1m = y1[x1_mask]
x2m = x2[x2_mask]
y2m = y2[x2_mask]

# Add all three regions together to get the full curve.
x = list(x1m) + list(xinter) + list(x2m)
y = list(y1m) + list(yi1+yi2) + list(y2m)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

You just have to be careful with the masking, and the boundaries could be created automatically I guess, but this is outside the scope of the question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is almost what i want. Is there any way to make the green line cover the whole area?( so for 1<x<3 , the green line should be on the blue one, and for 5<x<7, the green and orange should be on one another). And also, can i do what you wrote for more than 2 sets of x,y data in the same plot?

Comment: @PhilF. Yes it is possible to do it with as many data sets as you want, as long as the regions where you do the operation makes sense. Here we did the masking manually, but the best solution is to create a function `f(x1, y1, x2, y2)` dedicated to returning `x1[mask], y1[mask], x2[mask], y2[mask]` with `mask` along the lines of `(x1 in x2 ∩ x2 in x1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the full answer. I tried what you said and it works! Unfortunately, there are a lot of intersection masks because i have a lot of (x,y) sets and after some tries i still haven't got the right "sum" line for all of this, but i'll try more. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `y` values because the corresponding `x` values are different. To add them you will need `x` values in same ranges. For example in your code, the first point with addition will be the result of `f1(1) + f2(3)` which is not what you want. What you want is `f1(1) + f2(1)`

You should rather do

```
 xvals1=np.linspace(1,5,5)
 yinterp1 = np.interp(xvals1, x1, y1)
 plt.plot(xvals1, yinterp1)
 xvals2=np.linspace(1,5,5)
 yinterp2 = np.interp(xvals2, x2, y2)
 plt.plot(xvals2, yinterp2)
 xvals=np.linspace(1,5,5)
 plt.plot(xvals,yinterp1+yinterp2)
```

[image]

More over you will have to define the values of `y2` from `1` to `7` because you want the summation line form `1` to `7`.